# using "attribute" to connect result and the cause

Tags: style

Is it okay to use verb "attribute" when connecting some resultant situation with a person who might have caused it to happen?

For example,

> The situation in our small company is deplorable. Profits have dropped
>   almost to zero. However, I don't **attribute** this to our boss. Rather, I
>   would blame the whole lazy staff and managers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfectly fine way of using **attribute**.